# How to add an id property to a File?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input to upload [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). The uploaded files are shown as list displaying the file.name. When I add an id-property to a file it loses all it's properties except the path property. How can I add an id properly?

```
const fileWithId = {...uploadedFile, id: "myIdName"}  //does not work
```

Comment: This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you planning to do with that `id` property? It won't (for instance) be sent to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't copy `File` objects using spread syntax, they're largely-opaque data structures other than the [specified properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), which don't include an `id`.

You **might** be able to just assign an `id` property (since most objects in the browser environment are *extensible*, meaning you can add properties to them), but I wouldn't recommend it. The definition of the `File` object changes over time, and you never know, it might get an `id` property that means something different from your `id`. Separately, even if you did add an `id` to the object, I strongly doubt it would get sent to the server.

What you do instead will depend entirely on what you expect to do with the `File`. For instance, if this is just for client-side information, you might make your list a list of objects with `id` and `file` properties, where `file` is the original `File` object:

```
const fileWithId = {id: "myIdName", file: uploadedFile};
```

Or if sending to the server, send the file and the `id` together in the same form, etc.

Comment: Hi, if let's say i am creating the file object manually using File constructor and blob data got from canvas toBlob method callback and i need to add custom property to file which is some json data for that file and then I also need to send that file to server, does my new property (json) will be persisted or disappeared when it reaches server?

Comment: @ShashankBhatt - I very much doubt it. Instead, send the information separately in the same form as the file.